# Select Function Returns Object Not found

Tags: r, dplyr

This code was working the other day, now it spits out these object not found errors for the names of the columns I'm trying to pull. All of the columns exist in the CSV I'm importing. Any suggestions?

```
DF <- read.csv2("FILE PATHWAY", header=TRUE, sep = ",", stringsAsFactors = 
F, skip=1 )
DF <- DF[DF$Type=="AHREF",]
DF <- select(Type,Source,Destination)
# Error occurs here with this: Error in select(Type, Source, Destination) : object 'Type' not found
DF <- as.data.frame(sapply(DF,gsub,pattern="#URL DELETED",replacement=""))
DF <- as.data.frame(sapply(DF,gsub,pattern="#URL DELETED",replacement=""))
DF <- as.data.frame(sapply(DF,gsub,pattern="\"",replacement=""))
DF <- subset(DF, !grepl("^https", DF$Source))
DF <- subset(DF, !grepl("^https", DF$Destination))
colnames(DF) <- c("From","To")
rownames(DF) <- NULL
graphObject = graph.data.frame(DF, directed = TRUE)
graphObject = simplify(as.undirected(graphObject))
```

Comment: What is `DF` after this line? `DF <- DF[DF$Type=="AHREF",]` You had probably had an `attach(DF)` or `with` somewhere if this, and exactly this, was working for you before.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to make your question more likely to get an answer. Also you may want to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify the dataframe on which you apply the select.
Try this :

```
 DF <- select(DF,Type,Source,Destination)
```

or

```
 DF <- DF %>% select(Type,Source,Destination)
```

Comment: Reurns: Error in overscope_eval_next(overscope, expr) : object 'Type' not found

Comment: What is the output of : names(DF) ??

Comment: [1] "From" "To"   NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA

Comment: That is after you specified the names : colnames(DF) <- c("From","To").
But what had been  the output of : names(DF) before the error accured

Comment: Ah sorry, total R noob: [1] "AHREF"                  "https...hostway.com."   "https...hostway.com..1" "X68617"                 "Hostway"               
[6] "X"                      "X200"                   "OK"                     "TRUE."

Comment: it seems like you didnt read the column names. It seems  that the csv file you are reading misses the column names.

Comment: Try to specify them : i've just posted you another answer

Comment: I gave that a try, but the CSV has an excess line at the top so that makes sense to have. Essentially, I'm trying to make this guy's code work: https://data-seo.com/2015/07/07/r-tools-seo-part-1/